# Troubleshooting unequal error?

Tags: python, performance

I'm creating a LinkedList class to get a better feel for the python language and its doubly linked nodes. My overall task being to not make use of python's built-in list data structure, while also trying to optimize the time efficiency of the code. What would be the best way to go about fixing what I would assume is my **getitem** or **setitem** method body.

```
class LinkedList:
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, val, prior=None, next=None):
            self.val = val
            self.prior = prior
            self.next  = next

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = LinkedList.Node(None) # sentinel node (never to be removed)
        self.head.prior = self.head.next = self.head # set up "circular" topology
        self.length = 0


### prepend and append

    def prepend(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head, next=self.head.next)
        self.head.next.prior = self.head.next = n
        self.length += 1

    def append(self, value):
        n = LinkedList.Node(value, prior=self.head.prior, next=self.head)
        n.prior.next = n.next.prior = n
        self.length += 1


### subscript-based access ###

    def _normalize_idx(self, idx):
        nidx = idx
        if nidx < 0:
            nidx += len(self)
            if nidx < 0:
                nidx = 0
        return nidx

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `x = self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        for i in range(nidx):
            currNode = currNode.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        return currNode.val


    def __setitem__(self, idx, value):
        """Implements `self[idx] = x`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self[nidx]
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        currNode = value

    def __delitem__(self, idx):
        """Implements `del self[idx]`"""
        nidx = self._normalize_idx(idx)
        currNode = self.head.next
        if nidx >= len(self):
            raise IndexError
        for i in range(nidx+1, len(self)):
            self[i-1] = self[i]
        del self[len(self)-1]
```

Testing this code using:

```
    # test subscript-based access
from unittest import TestCase
import random

tc = TestCase()
data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lst = LinkedList()
for d in data:
    lst.append(d)

for i in range(len(data)):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    x = lst[100]

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    lst[100] = 0

with tc.assertRaises(IndexError):
    del lst[100]

lst[1] = data[1] = 20
del data[0]
del lst[0]

for i in range(len(data)):
    tc.assertEqual(lst[i], data[i])
```

I'd get an error saying 1 != 20. Writing these class methods always seems to trip me up, what might I be missing? I'm not exactly sure how this differs from the typical array backed list. And I'm not sure where this 20 value is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd get an error saying 1 != 20

That's a true statement, though, so your problem exists in how you set the data of your list. It wasn't updated, but the Python list was.

> I'm not sure where this 20 value is coming from

Umm... `lst[1] = data[1] = 20`,  perhaps?

Anyways, I don't think your setItem function is correct.  The `curNode` variable there is only a value, and not a `Node` object reference based upon the getItem method, so therefore, `currNode = value` is not actually updating the list, only the local variable scoped to that function.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure on how to set the item at the specified index then. If I were to alter the code adding something like `currNode = self.head[nidx]` I'll get an error, but I'm not sure how else to identify the proper node

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the list of Node objects much like you've done with getItem. Then instead of `return curNode.val`, you set its value.